# React Native - Navigation to other components not working

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to setup a button click to trigger another component to be opened. I'm trying open a component named "NameView" from my Landing view. However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

**landing.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { Svg } from 'react-native-svg'
import NameView from './name_view.js';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

export default function Welcome({ navigation }) {

    return (
        <View style={WelcomeStyles.Welcome}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={WelcomeStyles.Button} activeOpacity={0.6} underlayColor="#11132b" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NameView')}>
                    <View>
                        <View style={WelcomeStyles.ButtonBG} />
                        <Text style={WelcomeStyles.GetStarted}>Get Started</Text></View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

I have installed the react-navigation library as well. I'm guessing I'm declaring the navigation wrong here? Support with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accepting navigation as a prop here, could you declare it as a constant like this with useNavigation() ?

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Welcome() {

const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <View style={WelcomeStyles.Welcome}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={WelcomeStyles.Button} activeOpacity={0.6} underlayColor="#11132b" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NameView')}>
                    <View>
                        <View style={WelcomeStyles.ButtonBG} />
                        <Text style={WelcomeStyles.GetStarted}>Get Started</Text></View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I get an error: "The 'navigator' object hasn't been initialized yet". Any idea why?

Comment: Could you show me more of your navigation code?